# How can I scrape all the divs nested under a div into a list?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a webscraper using Selenium and BeautifulSoup.  I feel that the problem I am running into is more due to my lack of Python experience than due to experience with the libraries.  What my problem boils down to is that there are divs with no class nested under divs with a class that I want to scrape into a list.  I am not entirely sure how to run through those nested divs and put all the info into a list.  I believe that part of my issue is due to my inexperience using nested for loops in Python, as I believe the current for loops result in infinite loops.  Let me know what you come up with.  Thanks!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import os

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/myuser/Documents/geckodriverfolder/geckodriver")

driver.get('https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats?site=draftkings&sport=nba')

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

salary_opp = []
for test in soup.find_all('div', class_='rgt-col'):
  for test2 in soup.find_all('div'):
    draft_kings = test2.text
    salary_opp.append(draft_kings)

print(salary_opp)
```

This is what I had prior to the for loops, but it only put the first div nested under the singular div into a list:

```
for test in soup.find_all('div', class_='rgt-col'):
  draft_kings = test.div.text
  salary_opp.append(draft_kings)
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant html in the question? Or is it too big?

Comment: The easiest way to see that would be to go to https://rotogrinders.com/projected-stats?site=draftkings&sport=nba and use the web developer tools to inspect say the the salary column.  It is quite large.

Comment: you don't need to parse the entire page source with BS.  You can select the specific elements directly with selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the tags with no class, i.e. `<div>...</div>`, you can use `class_=None`.

```
for test in soup.find_all('div', class_='rgt-col'):
    for test2 in test.find_all('div', class_=None):
        draft_kings = test2.text
        salary_opp.append(draft_kings)
```

I did not check the logic behind your loops, but using `test.find_all('div', class_=None)` will answer your question. Also, note that I've changed the second `for` loop from `soup.find...` to `test.find...`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I believe the main problem here was my ineptitude regarding nested for loops in Python :).

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to learn that quickly. Also, have a look at [list comprehension in python.](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) You'll be able to do what you're doing right now pretty easily in one line. I could've provided you with that code too, but it's better if you try that one yourself.